# I am a bit confused as to what the code below is doing since I get the same results from both

Tags: java

```
String[] words = numOfWords.split("\\s+");

String[] words = numOfWords.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Maybe look at what trim does. Also, you should escape the backslash in the split regex.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) only removes leading and trailing white space characters. Unless `numOfWords` *starts* **or** *ends* with white space, I would expect them to be the same. For an example where the results differ, you could do something like

```
String[] words1 = " a b".split("\\s+");
String[] words2 = " a b".trim().split("\\s+");
System.out.printf("%s %s", Arrays.toString(words1), Arrays.toString(words2));
```

Which outputs

```
[, a, b] [a, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

.split will do something like "you, are , a, developer"
And the top line is doing that and using Regex to tell where to split the string.

The second line of code is doing the same thing with redundancy .